# Infected by rootkit. How do I remove it?

Tags: 12.04, server, rootkit

Today, I launched tiger, which did report a root kit alert. Chkrootkit did agree.

How can I remove this root kit ? How can I find how it was installed, so I can take care of the weakness in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS web server?

**Report of tiger:**

```
# Performing check for rookits...
# Running chkrootkit (/usr/sbin/chkrootkit) to perform further checks...
--ALERT-- [rootkit005a] Chkrootkit has found a file which seems to be infected 
          because of a rootkit 
--ALERT-- [rootkit009a] A rootkit seems to be installed in the system 
INFECTED (PORTS: 465)
```

**Report of chkrootkit:**

```
Checking `bindshell'...                                     INFECTED (PORTS:  465)
```

**Additional details :**

```
$ netstat --all --numeric-ports --program |grep 465
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2283/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      2283/master
```

Comment: You appear to be running Postfix on port 465 - an alternative SMTP port. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

It might be a [false positive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19868/chkrootkit-warning-about-infected-port-600).

Linked from the above link. [This post](http://osdir.com/ml/mandrake.security.general/2006-09/msg00014.html) from 2006.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems there is something running on port 465. I updated my question accordingly.